# How to get the corresponding date for an earnings release in PINE (Tradingview)

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to create a table in Tradingview (PINE code) showing the earnings of the last quarters with the corresponding date acc. to.

```
EPS_a = request.earnings(syminfo.tickerid, earnings.actual, barmerge.gaps_off)

f_EPS_a(i) => request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1M', EPS_a[I])

var table tab_EPS = table.new(...)

if barstate.islast
    table.cell(tab_EPS, 0, 0, str.tostring(f_EPS_a(4)))
    table.cell(tab_EPS, 1, 0, "Corresponding date")
```

How is the code to get the corresponding date of the earnings release?

Thank you very much